# Find the value of a variable in all instances of a class

Tags: java

I am new in java. I want to check one variable of a class for all instances. if this variable do not have a certain value in all instances i will do the next step. but i can not do this. e.g. in my code if the Type of all instancesses of class Proposition are not "UserModelMatch" i will do "continue".

```
 Proposition proposition=new Proposition();

      for (Proposition proposition:Proposition)

          if (!proposition.getType().equals("UserModelMatch") {
                     .....do next
            }
```

---

```
 public class Propositions extends ArrayList<Proposition>{ 
    }
```

but this code check for one proposition and if it do not contain the Type "UserModelNoMatch"
it will "do next ". but first,I want to check all the Type for all propositions, which they are in "Proposition" and then if there is  any "UserModelMatch " then te propgram will do next step.

Comment: Java has no concept at all of 'all instances'. If you need to keep a list of all the instances of a class, you need to keep that list yourself.

Comment: And where are all instances of `Proposition`?

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm you need in pseudo-code:

```
boolean areAllEquals = true
for each proposition do
    if type != "the value" then
        areAllEquals = false
        break
    endif
endfor
if areAllEquals then
    // all types are equals
else
    // there is at least two different types
endif
```

A `break` statement stops the parent loop iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Generally: you need to maintain references to the instances that you're looking for, then iterate over them and check for membership.  Trying to iterate over a Class doesn't work like you think it does.

Also, you need to fix your broken code.

```
Proposition proposition=new proposition();
```

Capitalization matters.  Proposition != proposition

```
  for (Proposition proposition:Proposition)
```

Don't shadow variables that you just created.  `for (Proposition p: proposition)` is probably what you meant to write, though I think you're just generally confused about what you can iterate over.  You again need to have a list of instances to iterate over, not just the name of the type.

Lastly, use the `instanceof` keyword instead of using reflection.